# Magento 2 Class Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Attributes does not exist

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

I have the following error when trying to access Magento 2.

> Class
> Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Attributes
> does not exist

This happen after removed Porto Theme. SmartWave. Mageplaza. can you help me fix it ? I have run the below commands but no success :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
// -f to use in default and developer mode
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Noted that frontend is not accessible while backend its ok.

Thank you !!

Comment: I have same error when accesing Category on admin panel.

Comment: Just remove references to `Mageplaza` in `eav_attribute` table and flush cache. Check all fields end with `_model`.

Comment: @Victor thaanks for your reply. I found this on easv_attribute : backend_model` = 'Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Attributes' and `source_model` = 'Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Attributes'

Comment: Do you mean to delete all this row ?

Comment: No. Ideally need to restore default value, but you can just set to empty. Please specify found attributes and i will advise default values (if they are exists)

Comment: attribute_id = 137
entity_type_id = 3 
attribute_code = mp_ln_hide_attribute_ids
attribute_model = NULL
backend_model = Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Attributes 
backend_type = text
backend_table = NULL
frontend_model = NULL
frontend_input = multiselect
frontend_label = Hide Filter Attributes on Layered Navigation
frontend_class = NULL
source_model = Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Attributes
is_required = 0
is_user_defined = 0
default_value = NULL
is_unique = 0
note = NULL

Comment: In this case you can just delete this row

Comment: Thank you  error fixed , page now appearing and  one more error appear Invalid block type: Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList

Comment: Check `cms_page` table `content` column and layout files in your theme

Comment: I deleted all content about this theme on cms_page but still got Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList  another  part check ?

Comment: THANKS FIXED IT

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by simply removing reference to `Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Attributes` from the backend model in your DB eav_attribute table.

[image]

Query to run:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'Mageplaza%LayeredNavigation%Model%';
```

Comment: Work Perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Work perfectly, i remove one db line and all is running again